# Permanent redirect (301) for Google Drive Site Publishing

Tags: search-engine, google-docs, http-status-code-301, google-drive-api

Ref: http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/11/announcing-google-drive-site-publishing.html

Is there a way to set a Permanent redirect (301) for the content published using Google Drive Site Publishing. We are moving the content to a new site and would to have the traffic redirected.

.htaccess doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of modifying the response code, sorry. You could use a `<meta>` redirect, of course, but that is not ideal, sorry.